# deviation in gps coördinates android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was wondering if there is any deviation or bug in de android 1.6 emulator on GPS coordinates.

when I search by Google maps on the GPS coordinates `51.501563,-0.12534` then I get "Canon Row" in London, but when i put this coordinates in the emulator(`geo fix -0.12534 51.501563`) the the emulator shows in Google maps(on the emulator) a different location(A301 bridge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geo fix command of the emulator isn't accurate enough for precise locations.